# Do fish need a dark environment at night?

Tags: fish, aquarium

Is it bad if I accidentally leave the lights lit on a fish tank overnight? Or do the fish not care whether it is light or dark?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fish do care if it´s day or night: they have a [cicardian rhythm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circadian_rhythm) and many physiological events are related to the day / night time. Light could interfere with that. Source: [this book](http://professeur.umoncton.ca/umcm-reebs_stephan/files/umcm-reebs_stephan/wf/wf/pdf/Fish%20circadian%20rhythms%20book%20chapter.pdf), chapter 6.

Even [blind fish can have a cicardian rhythm](http://www.plosbiology.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pbio.1001142)

Leaving the aquarium light accidentally lit for one night won´t instantly kill them but will cause some stress.

Comment: Why not just connect your lights to a timer that will shut it off automatically at a given time each day?!

Comment: Also leaving the lights on for long periods can increase algae growth - which, as well as being unsightly, can decrease oxygen levels in the tank.

Comment: As an addendum, the night is also required for some plants. Compare for example [this question](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3402/can-plants-have-too-much-light-or-do-they-need-night-rest).

Answer (score -1):

I would set a light with a timer, fish are less active when the tank is dark and can get stressed, which means they are more vulnerable to illness.